# openssl RSA_public_encrypt() returned size always = RSA_size(rsa)?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, rsa

`RSA_size(rsa)` returns modulus which equals to 256 in my application.
and I am encrypting the data with `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING` option, so the max length of the input buffer sent to `RSA_public_encrypt()` is 256 - 41 = 215

In some case, the length of my input buffer may exceeds the 215 limitation a bit, and I need call `RSA_public_encrypt()` multitimes.

My question is about the return value of `RSA_public_encrypt()`.

From my test the return value is 256 (equals to `RSA_size(rsa)` ), 
and the [doc](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_public_encrypt.html) also says:

> RSA_public_encrypt() returns the size of the encrypted data (i.e.,
>   RSA_size(rsa)).

I just want to make sure that there will only be two possibilities for the return value of  `RSA_public_encrypt()`.

**-1 (error)** or **modulus(success)**,  and there is no other possiblity, yes?
I am curious because I need dividing the encrypted buffer and call `RSA_private_decrypt()` for each of the block. If the encrypted buffer of each `RSA_public_encrypt` is the same, then I don't need store the size for each of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The (positive) return of a RSA_public_encrypt() will always be the same as the RSA_size(rsa) for all current known modes of PKCS#1 encryption.

So in short: your current assumptions are correct.

Practically though: If you have data that is larger than the RSA_size(rsa) and you are splitting it into blocks, you should probably think about encrypting the data with a random symmetric key and encrypting that key with your RSA_public_key(). RSA public key encryption is not meant to be used over larger blocks of data.

The best way to encrypt things that are larger than RSA_size(rsa) - XX (Where XX is dependent on the PKCS#1 mode used):

- Generate a random **IV** of 16 bytes (Should be unique)
- Generate a random key **K** of 32 bytes (256 bits)
- Encrypt the data with **K** and **IV** using either AES-CBC (think about padding) or AES-CTR into **E-DATA**
- Hash the encrypted data **E-DATA** with SHA-256 (or any suitable hash algorithm for your situation) into hash **H**
- Encrypt with RSA Public key the **IV**, key **K** and the hash **H** (**IV** can be public as well, but this is often easier) into **E-RSA**
- Send encrypted data **E-DATA** and encrypted key-data **E-RSA** to other side

On the other side:

- Decrypt **E-RSA** into **IV**, **K** and **H** (Bail out if it fails)
- Hash **E-DATA** and check with **H** (Bail out if it fails)
- Decrypt **E-DATA** with **IV** and **K**
- Done..

Comment: In such case much better is to use proven-to-work and already established scheme, like CMS, which is also supported by OpenSSL. This is reinvention of the wheel.

Comment: @NickolayO. this is a much better answer than yours, and I got the feeling you downvoted it. If you think the questioner is better suited to CMS, *then post it as an answer*.

Comment: I have another opinion on quality of this answer, however I'm also don't think that my answer is ideal.

Comment: @NickolayO I agree that it is good to use established schemes, such as CMS in most situations. Not everybody can use OpenSSL on both sides. And ipmlementing CMS outside of OpenSSL is quiet a hellish experience, because of the ASN.1 encoding. So yes, I agree. Use CMS in case you can..

Comment: You don't need to implement CMS/OpenPGP yourself, there are a lot of libraries available for almost any language. And, OpenSSL is available for all platforms (as well as GnuPG).

Comment: @NickolayO I don't agree there. It depends on your view of the world of platforms I guess.. PC platforms, yes.. Embedded platforms, some, most not.. Non-standard OS, no..

Comment: I use almost the same encrypting scheme, a little bit more complex though. OpenSSL is not a variant for me, and for many other indie devs I think

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that output of RSA_encrypt() will contain some leading zero bits, and I'm not sure if openssl preserves them. Cutting them will result in output, which is one byte shorter.
This can happen rarely.

If your input only abit larger, why not to increase the size of the RSA key? You can have 2536-bit RSA key, or 3072bit, whatever else.

Comment: Likely they use `BN_bn2bin` which is only defined for positive "big numbers". Increasing the size is an option, but you have to know the maximum size in advance. It's much less flexible and much slower than generating a symmetric key (well, depending on the speed of the secure random generator, of course) - and with slower I mean *exponential* slow down when related to key size.

Comment: For sure it is much better to use already-known mixed symmetric/assymetric scheme like OpenPGP or CMS.